# java regular expression find a string add it to array and then replace original

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have a string of text like this:

```
This is a[WAIT] test.
```

What I want to do is search the string for a substring that starts with [ and ends with ]
Each one I find I want to add it to an ArrayList and replace substring in original string with a ^

Here is my regex:

```
String regex_script = "/^\\[\\]$/"; //Match a string which starts with the character [ ending in the character ]
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex_script); // Create a pattern to match
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);  // Create a matcher with an input string
boolean result = m.find();
        while(result) {
                m.appendReplacement(sb, "^");
                result = m.find();
        }
        m.appendTail(sb); // Add the last segment of input to the new String
```

how would I got about doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do:

```
    String regex_script = "\\[([^\\]]*)\\]";

    String line = "This is a[WAIT] testThis is a[WAIT] test";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();   //use to record

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex_script); // Create a pattern to match
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line); // Create a matcher with an input string

    while (m.find()) {
        list.add(m.group(1));
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "[^]");
    }
    m.appendTail(sb); // Add the last segment of input to the new String

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: worked great! THANKS - the issue was not being familiar with how certain escape sequences affected the pattern.

Comment: @ouotuo Hi, can you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938232/android-regex-passing-of-text-output-from-method-to-method

Answer (score -1):

If you are searching a substring, don't use ^ and $. Those are for beginning and at end at a string (not a word) Try:

```
String regex_script = "/\[.*\]/";
```

Comment: No, inside a String literal in Java, a backslash would need to be escaped again, and Java's regex-es are not delimited with a char like `/`.